# Converting a pdf to html and then to textarea

Tags: php, jquery, pdf

Here is what I am trying to achieve.

I have a (php) webpage where users can upload a pdf document. The webpage has two columns. Once upload of the file is finished, using jQuery/ajax and php

- I need to convert the pdf document to a semantic html in div_left.
- I need to give user the ability to drag a part of html content and transfer the content to textarea (new content).

The pdf document is not standard in terms of format and the content layout. so it is imperative that the tool requires a way to select the content from the left to the textareas on the right. In the process tool is will help standardise the content.

---

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div id="div_left"></div>
                <div id="div_right">
                    <textarea name="" id="newcontent1" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><textarea name="" id="newcontent2" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy as you mean, but to achieve this, you have to use a converter, that will convert your pdf into a readable format, with which you can work.

I did something like this years ago, my way was to use pdftotext (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/pdftotext.htm) to convert the pdf into a html file and use this html file to snip out the needed content.

You have to try, there is no chance to make a snippet from where you can start, because you give no information about the pdf itself.

## Update: Procedure

1. Convert your your file into a htmlfile with pdftotext (-htmlmeta flag)
2. Load the converted File with a jquery ajax call, then you can snip out with jquery whatever you want and put it whereever you want, or even attach new functions like drag and drop.

Have a look on pdttotext with the -htmlmeta flag - you will see, that the generated file is a readable html file.

Comment: Added more clarification on the pdf following your input. The pdf is not in a standard format but on transferring the snippets from the left to the textareas on the right helps to standardise.

Comment: Try it with pdftotext as mentioned before ....  i did update my answer to clarifiy the steps you should go with.